# Validation on UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have created a `UITextField` and I want to give validations for the textfield(userName) such that only characters are allowed. If the user enters anything else other than a alphabet like numbers or special characters, it shouldn't appear and also there should be a notification to show the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if(textField==YOUR_TEXTFIELD_NAME)
        {
            NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
            for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
                unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
                if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Numbers not allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                    return NO;
                }

            }

    }
return YES;
}
```

Make sure you set the delegate for your textfield.

Comment: thanks for Replay but  This code number also allowed

Comment: 1. Did you connect your UITextField with IBOutlet? 2. Did you set the UITextFieldDelegate to your textfield?

Comment: Sir, downvoter.. care to explain why the downvote? :/

Answer (score 3):

```
#define ALPHA @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


    NSCharacterSet *blockedCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ALPHA] invertedSet];

    if (!([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound)) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Only allow alphabet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    return ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this 

NSCharacterSet *blockedCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
{
    return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharacters].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_NUMBER @"1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

        NSCharacterSet *acceptedInput = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_NUMBER]invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:acceptedInput] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        if ((![filtered isEqualToString:string]))
            return NO;
    }

}
```